# Link to next activity

Tags: moodle

I have written a number of courses which follow a similar pattern.

- Lesson 1
- Lesson 2
- Lesson n
- Quiz
- Evaluation

I link from at the end of each activity using the "Link to next activity" configuration option in the 'Appearance' section when you edit the settings of the Lesson. The last lesson links to the Quiz.

However, I cannot find how to link from the Quiz to the Evaluation. There doesn't appear to be any "Link to next activity" configuration for a Quiz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one type of activity where the "Link to next activity" link can be used. This activity is [Lesson](https://docs.moodle.org/31/en/Lesson_activity), exactly the one you used. This function has been implemented in no other activity. I checked this in Moodle versions 2.7.8 and 2.9.6.1 (one of the last versions).

Comment: Thank you. That is very clear. Do you have any suggestions about what I could do instead?

Comment: Hmmmm. What I could think is a kind of trick. You could 1) create your "Evaluation" activity; 2) copy the web link of this activity somewhere; 3) Go into your Quiz settings page and write into its "Overall feedback" section your saved link, putting it into a text like, say "Go here", or "Go ahead". The "Overall feedback is text that is shown after a quiz has been attempted." So, I presume this text is shown only afterwards the test has been attempted.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this answer come to late, there is a block plugin that provide a 'jump to' menu https://moodle.org/plugins/block_jumpto_menu

Comment: Hi @pablop22. Never too late. Can your suggested solution be used at the end of a quiz? The screenshot in the description looked quite different.

Answer (score 0):

The Moodle block Jump To Navigation/"jump_to_menu" has not been updated for 7 years and will probably not work on current versions of Moodle. Instead I recommend the [Navigation buttons block](https://moodle.org/plugins/block_navbuttons), tested on latest Moodle 4.1.1.